# Upload Entire Directory via PHP FTP

Tags: php, upload, ftp, directory

I'm trying to write a script that will upload the entire contents of a directory stored on my server to other servers via ftp.

I've been reading through the [documentation on www.php.net](http://php.net/ftp/), but can't seem to find a way to upload more then one file at a time.

Is there a way to do this, or is there a script that will index that directory and create an array of files to upload?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 12):

Once you have a connection open, uploading the contents of a directory serially is simple:

```
foreach (glob("/directory/to/upload/*.*") as $filename)
    ftp_put($ftp_stream, basename($filename) , $filename, FTP_BINARY);
```

Uploading all files in parallel would be more difficult.

Answer (score 6):

So, I took @iYETER's code, and wrapped it as a class object.

You can call this code by these lines:

```
$ftp = new FtpNew("hostname");

$ftpSession = $ftp->login("username", "password");

if (!$ftpSession) die("Failed to connect.");

$errorList = $ftp->send_recursive_directory("/local/dir/", "/remote/dir/");
print_r($errorList);

$ftp->disconnect();
```

It recursively crawls local dir, and places it on remote dir relative. If it hits any errors, it creates a array hierarchy of every file and their exception code (I only capture 2 so far, if it's another error, it throws it default route for now)

The class this is wrapped into:

```
<?php
//Thanks for iYETER on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/927341/upload-entire-directory-via-php-ftp

class FtpNew {
private $connectionID;
private $ftpSession = false;
private $blackList = array('.', '..', 'Thumbs.db');
public function __construct($ftpHost = "") {
    if ($ftpHost != "") $this->connectionID = ftp_connect($ftpHost);
}

public function __destruct() {
    $this->disconnect();
}

public function connect($ftpHost) {     
    $this->disconnect();
    $this->connectionID = ftp_connect($ftpHost);
    return $this->connectionID;
}

public function login($ftpUser, $ftpPass) {
    if (!$this->connectionID) throw new Exception("Connection not established.", -1);
    $this->ftpSession = ftp_login($this->connectionID, $ftpUser, $ftpPass);
    return $this->ftpSession;
}

public function disconnect() {
    if (isset($this->connectionID)) {
        ftp_close($this->connectionID);
        unset($this->connectionID);
    }
}

public function send_recursive_directory($localPath, $remotePath) {
    return $this->recurse_directory($localPath, $localPath, $remotePath);
}

private function recurse_directory($rootPath, $localPath, $remotePath) {
    $errorList = array();
    if (!is_dir($localPath)) throw new Exception("Invalid directory: $localPath");
    chdir($localPath);
    $directory = opendir(".");
    while ($file = readdir($directory)) {
        if (in_array($file, $this->blackList)) continue;
        if (is_dir($file)) {
            $errorList["$remotePath/$file"] = $this->make_directory("$remotePath/$file");
            $errorList[] = $this->recurse_directory($rootPath, "$localPath/$file", "$remotePath/$file");
            chdir($localPath);
        } else {
            $errorList["$remotePath/$file"] = $this->put_file("$localPath/$file", "$remotePath/$file");
        }
    }
    return $errorList;
}

public function make_directory($remotePath) {
    $error = "";
    try {
        ftp_mkdir($this->connectionID, $remotePath);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        if ($e->getCode() == 2) $error = $e->getMessage(); 
    }
    return $error;
}

public function put_file($localPath, $remotePath) {
    $error = "";
    try {
        ftp_put($this->connectionID, $remotePath, $localPath, FTP_BINARY); 
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        if ($e->getCode() == 2) $error = $e->getMessage(); 
    }
    return $error;
}
}
```

Comment: The class is great but fails when passive mode is needed. 
The login() function needs to be enhanced by 

ftp_pasv($this->connectionID, true);

Answer (score 2):

Do it in a loop, iterating through all the files in the folder

```
$servername = $GLOBALS["servername"];
    $ftpUser = $GLOBALS["ftpUser"];
    $ftpPass = $GLOBALS["ftpPass"];
$conn_id = ftp_connect($servername) or die("<p style=\"color:red\">Error connecting to $servername </p>");

if(ftp_login($conn_id, $ftpUser, $ftpPass))
{
    $dir_handle = @opendir($path) or die("Error opening $path");

         while ($file = readdir($dir_handle)) {
            ftp_put($conn_id, PATH_TO_REMOTE_FILE, $file)
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I coded it, the script uploads whole folder with it's subfolders and files.

I hope it will help you.

```
<?php 
ob_start(); 
set_time_limit(0); 
//r10.net fatal

$anadizin="uploadedeceginizdizin"; //this is the folder that you want to upload with all subfolder and files of it.

$ftpsunucu="domain.com"; //ftp domain name
$ftpusername="ftpuser";  //ftp user name 
$ftppass="ftppass"; //ftp passowrd
$ftpdizin="/public_html"; //ftp main folder





$arkadaslarlabardaydik = ftp_connect($ftpsunucu); 
$ictikguldukeglendik = ftp_login($arkadaslarlabardaydik, $ftpusername, $ftppass); 

if((!$arkadaslarlabardaydik) || (!$ictikguldukeglendik))  
{ 
  echo "cant connect!"; 
  die(); 
} 


function klasoruoku($dizinadi) 
{ 
  global $nerdeyiz,$fulldizin,$ftpdizin,$arkadaslarlabardaydik,$ftpdizin; 

  chdir($dizinadi."\\"); 
  $dizin = opendir("."); 

  while($bilgi=readdir($dizin))  
  { 
    if ($bilgi!='.' and $bilgi!='..' and $bilgi!="Thumbs.db") 
    {  
        $tamyol="$dizinadi\\$bilgi"; 

        $lokalkla=str_replace("".$nerdeyiz."\\","",$dizinadi).""; 
        $lokaldosya="$lokalkla\\$bilgi"; 
        $ftpyeyolla=str_replace(array("\\\\","\\"),array("/","/"),"$ftpdizin\\".str_replace("".$fulldizin."","",$dizinadi)."\\$bilgi"); 

        if(!is_dir($bilgi)) 
        { 
          $yükleme = ftp_put($arkadaslarlabardaydik, $ftpyeyolla, $tamyol, FTP_BINARY); 

          if (!$yükleme)  
          { 
              echo "$lokaldosya <font color=red>uploaded</font>"; echo "<br>";  fls(); 
          }  
          else  
          { 
              echo "$lokaldosya <font color=green>not uploaded</font>"; echo "<br>"; fls(); 
          } 
        } 
        else 
        {  
          ftp_mkdir($arkadaslarlabardaydik, $ftpyeyolla); 
          klasoruoku("$dizinadi\\$bilgi"); 
          chdir($dizinadi."\\"); 
          fls(); 
        } 
    } 
  } 
  closedir ($dizin); 
} 

function fls() 
{ 
    ob_end_flush(); 
    ob_flush(); 
    flush(); 
    ob_start(); 
} 

$nerdeyiz=getcwd(); 
$fulldizin=$nerdeyiz."\\$anadizin"; 
klasoruoku($fulldizin); 
ftp_close($arkadaslarlabardaydik); 

?>
```

Comment: I wish the variables were written in english :( I upvoted you anyways

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have multiple files uploaded at once, you'll need to use thread or fork.

I'm not sure of a Thread implentation in PHP, but you should take a look at the [PHP SPL](http://fr3.php.net/manual/en/book.spl.php) and/or [PEAR](http://pear.php.net/)

**Edit:** Thanks to Frank Farmer to let me know that there was a fork() function in PHP known as [pcntl_fork()](https://www.php.net/pcntl_fork)

You'll also have to get the whole content directory recursively to be able to upload all the file for a given directory.

Comment: PHP doesn't thread, but it does fork (using pcntl_fork()), and there are some thread-like wrappers for PHP's fork functionality.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using forks. That's hairy stuff. It's far easier to simply open multiple connections and use a socket_select() to write to then asynchronously.